# git push error "fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'"

Tags: github

I've added remote origin like:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/username/repo.git
```

When I push the git repository, I get this error:

```
git push -u origin master
fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'
```

I am on git 1.7.1 on Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS

Any ideas, greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much searching, the answer is you need git version 1.7.7

[Can't update RVM - "fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'http'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569089/cant-update-rvm-fatal-unable-to-find-remote-helper-for-http)

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others will be able to learn from your success.  Cheers~

Comment: The issue can exist in versions of git >= 1.7.7

Answer (score 10):

If you compiled git from source, be sure to install this package first:

`apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev`

Answer (score 4):

I just got the problem yesterday and solved it today, so am posting in case this might help a Windows user. For me, the problem occurred after I updated to the latest version of Git (because Visual Studio was recommending I do so-- something about things not matching.)

It turns out that I installed in the default directory Program Files, but my old Git was in Program Files (x86). (Hadn't noticed until tried reinstalling.)

Uninstalling the new version and installing the 64-bit Git for Windows Setup listed under Other Git for Windows downloads (which is not the default) overlaying the version in Program Files (x86) worked. (I tried other combinations of version and folders first.)

I did have to delete the local repository already created and restart with git init, git add ., git commit -m "first commit", git remote add origin theGitUrl (all of which worked before), before doing the git push origin master. The weird thing is that a pop-up window appeared to enter my user name and password. I didn't notice it at first and thought the processing on the git push was hung up. So, heads up about that "Other Git for Windows" version.

I did change my Environmental Variables before the fix; I don't know if that helped. I added these 2 to the PATH: 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\libexec\git-core
I did this for both User and System variables.

A note on updating the PATH in Windows 10: you have to add one at a time and not include the ;

Comment: Just adding the path to the environment varialbles and modifying the android studio settings to use the git.exe from the git installed path solved the issue for me!

Answer (score 1):

I was working in a chroot jail and thought i had copied everything i needed for git to work but i was missing the git-core files themselves so i just had to copy them:

```
cp -r /usr/lib/git-core /opt/chroot/myjail/usr/lib/
```

Answer (score -3):

```
Add this to git config: (Checked in centos 6.7 and working)
    #git config --global url.https://.insteadOf git://

#To see the config added
    #git config --list
    url.https://.insteadof=git://
    user.name=username
    user.email=youremail
    ....
```