# Git 1.7.11 Debian fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'

Tags: git, debian

I'm using bitbucket along with git to manage a project. I've experience no problems under windows development environment however i'm having issues in debian squeeze. The problem is not present at clone, only on push. The error i'm getting is:

fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'

I've tried compile it with curl, tried installing several version of curl, but no success. In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10928215/git-push-error-fatal-unable-to-find-remote-helper-for-https) the git version was 1.7.1 and the answer was to move to 1.7.7, however my version of git is 1.7.11

How can i fix this?

**Update:**

My [config.log](http://pastebin.com/zib5ZfJ2) says NO_CURL=''

I have no problem using curl by itself with https

**Update2:**

my config also says NO_OPENSSL = ''

Doing a find -name git-remote-* on root shows me the following:

```
./usr/share/man/man1/git-remote-helpers.1.gz
./usr/local/libexec/git-core/git-remote-fd
./usr/local/libexec/git-core/git-remote-ext
./usr/local/libexec/git-core/git-remote-https
./usr/local/libexec/git-core/git-remote-testgit
./usr/local/libexec/git-core/git-remote-ftps
./usr/local/libexec/git-core/git-remote-ftp
./usr/local/libexec/git-core/git-remote-http
./usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-https
./usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-testgit
./usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-ftps
./usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-ftp
./usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-http
./home/osednaca/git-1.7.11/git-remote-ftps
./home/osednaca/git-1.7.11/git-remote-ext
./home/osednaca/git-1.7.11/git-remote-https
./home/osednaca/git-1.7.11/git-remote-testgit.py
./home/osednaca/git-1.7.11/git-remote-ftp
./home/osednaca/git-1.7.11/git-remote-fd
./home/osednaca/git-1.7.11/Documentation/git-remote-helpers.txt
./home/osednaca/git-1.7.11/Documentation/git-remote-fd.txt
./home/osednaca/git-1.7.11/Documentation/git-remote-testgit.txt
./home/osednaca/git-1.7.11/Documentation/git-remote-ext.txt
./home/osednaca/git-1.7.11/git-remote-testgit
./home/osednaca/git-1.7.11/git-remote-http
./home/osednaca/git-1.7.11/contrib/mw-to-git/git-remote-mediawiki
./home/osednaca/git-1.7.11/contrib/mw-to-git/git-remote-mediawiki.txt
```

Comment: How did you get this version of git?  Compile it yourself?  Install some package?  Which one?

Comment: I had the version that came with debian repository, then got the problem and compile it myself but the same problem happend

Comment: Do you have git-remote-http?  `ls /usr/libexec/git-core/git-remote*` might work, but your path may vary.  Do you have the libcurl development package installed?  Does curl support https URLs if you try?  Do you have openssl and the openssl-devel library installed?

Comment: Specifically libssl-dev and libcurl4-openssl-dev

Comment: @SethRobertson just tried curl with https and works ok. And have no file like git-remote* and i dont have libcurl4-openssl-dev. Which is the exact procedure i should follow?

Comment: Then when you compiled git it was unable to find/use libcurl, possibly because you didn't have the libcurl*-dev package installed.  Make sure you have libssl-dev installed as well.  When you recompile git perhaps you should use the configure method after which you can inspect config.log to see if it found CURL (NO_CURL should not be set)

Comment: @SethRobertson ok, config log: NO_CURL='', is that good? Still same error.

Comment: Yes, it found libcurl.  Did it build git-remote-* commands `ls git-remote-*`?  Did it find openssl `grep OPENSSL config.log`?

Comment: @SethRobertson NO_OPENSSL = ''. I finally did a find -name git-remote-* on root and found out that there is a mess, see my update and help me out please!

Comment: Please paste the command and output of `GIT_TRACE=1 git push`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you were to **strace -f** this you would see it actually is trying to find that helper, but in system path. To change that root you can use --exec-path or GIT_EXEC_PATH.

For example say I wget'd git-core from the archive, and dpkg -x into ~/opt, I would then

```
export GIT_EXEC_PATH=/home/ppetraki/opt/usr/lib/git-core
```

where,

```
find ~/ -name git-remote-https
/home/ppetraki/opt/usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-https
```

Use this to debug,

```
strace -f $FOO/usr/bin/git clone https://uri > trace.out 2>&1
```

Hope this helps.