# npm ERR! fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'

Tags: git, npm, react-native

I'm running `npm install` in a React Native project from a remote session.
More specifically, this `npm install` is part of my build script running by [VSTS agent](https://github.com/microsoft/vsts-agent/).
and I ran into this error.

```
npm ERR! git fetch -a origin (https://github.com/mtunique/react-native-scrollable-tab-view.git) fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'
npm ERR! Darwin 15.4.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/5.4.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v5.4.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! Command failed: git fetch -a origin
npm ERR! fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/**/npm-debug.log
```

What I've found but not working:

- ["Unable to find remote helper for 'https'" during git clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329485/unable-to-find-remote-helper-for-https-during-git-clone)
- [Git 1.7.11 Debian fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552450/git-1-7-11-debian-fatal-unable-to-find-remote-helper-for-https)

Answer (score 0):

Figured out it's caused by a npm bug https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/13353,
it's fixed via https://github.com/npm/npm/pull/13358 and released in npm v3.10.7.

So, just update your npm will work.

Comment: I currently have npm 3.10.10 and I am getting this error.

Comment: getting same problem with npm 3.10.10