# error when I write "meteor npm install"

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm

I get the following error message when running my meteor application

```
C:\Users\connect\Desktop\help-er\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:467
W20171125-17:34:04.961(2)? (STDERR) }).run();
W20171125-17:34:04.961(2)? (STDERR)    ^
W20171125-17:34:04.962(2)? (STDERR)
W20171125-17:34:04.962(2)? (STDERR) Error: The babel-runtime npm package could not be found in your node_modules
W20171125-17:34:04.963(2)? (STDERR) directory. Please run the following command to install it:
W20171125-17:34:04.963(2)? (STDERR)
W20171125-17:34:04.963(2)? (STDERR)   meteor npm install --save babel-runtime
W20171125-17:34:04.964(2)? (STDERR)
W20171125-17:34:04.964(2)? (STDERR)     at babel-runtime.js (packages\babel-runtime.js:36:9)
W20171125-17:34:04.965(2)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages\modules-runtime.js:343:9)
W20171125-17:34:04.965(2)? (STDERR)     at require (packages\modules-runtime.js:238:16)
W20171125-17:34:04.965(2)? (STDERR)     at packages\babel-runtime.js:155:15
W20171125-17:34:04.966(2)? (STDERR)     at packages\babel-runtime.js:166:3
W20171125-17:34:04.966(2)? (STDERR)     at infos.forEach.info (C:\Users\connect\Desktop\help-er\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:414:13)
W20171125-17:34:04.966(2)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
W20171125-17:34:04.969(2)? (STDERR)     at C:\Users\connect\Desktop\help-er\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:413:9
W20171125-17:34:04.969(2)? (STDERR)     at C:\Users\connect\Desktop\help-er\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:463:5
W20171125-17:34:04.970(2)? (STDERR)     at Function.run (C:\Users\connect\Desktop\help-er\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\profile.js:510:12)
```

and the following error when I run the following command

```
meteor npm install --save babel-runtime
```

the error :

```
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t https://github.com/meteor/readable-stream.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'
npm ERR!
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\connect\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-11-25T15_36_26_586Z-debug.log
```

the log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Users\\connect\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.6.0\\mt-os.windows.x86_64\\dev_bundle\\bin\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\connect\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.6.0\\mt-os.windows.x86_64\\dev_bundle\\lib\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '--save',
1 verbose cli   'babel-runtime' ]
2 info using npm@5.4.2
3 info using node@v8.8.1
4 verbose npm-session f78dcd8e95220926
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/babel-runtime 786ms (from cache)
8 silly pacote range manifest for babel-runtime@^6.26.0 fetched in 1568ms
9 silly install loadIdealTree
10 silly install cloneCurrentTreeToIdealTree
11 silly install loadShrinkwrap
12 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for readable-stream@git+https://github.com/meteor/readable-stream.git#d64a64aa6061b9b6855feff4d09e58fb3b2e4502 Error while executing:
12 silly fetchPackageMetaData C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t https://github.com/meteor/readable-stream.git
12 silly fetchPackageMetaData
12 silly fetchPackageMetaData fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'
12 silly fetchPackageMetaData
12 silly fetchPackageMetaData exited with error code: 128
13 verbose stack Error: exited with error code: 128
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.onexit (C:\Users\connect\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.6.0\mt-os.windows.x86_64\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\end-of-stream\index.js:39:36)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
14 verbose cwd C:\Users\connect\Desktop\help-er
15 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.15063
16 verbose argv "C:\\Users\\connect\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.6.0\\mt-os.windows.x86_64\\dev_bundle\\bin\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\connect\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.6.0\\mt-os.windows.x86_64\\dev_bundle\\lib\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save" "babel-runtime"
17 verbose node v8.8.1
18 verbose npm  v5.4.2
19 error Error while executing:
19 error C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t https://github.com/meteor/readable-stream.git
19 error
19 error fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'
19 error
19 error exited with error code: 128
20 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

any idea why I am getting these errors ?

Comment: Check your log file, its for a reason

Comment: @wrangler I can't , it tells me that my post is mostly code and I have to put more details and I don't know what else to write

Comment: @wrangler I added it as text

Comment: Looks like you've hit [this bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39138990/1745073)

Answer (score 0):

Running in cmd shell as admin in windows 10 fixed similar issue for me.

Was getting this is regular cmd shell

```
c:\meteor\simple-todos>meteor npm install --save font-awesome
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t https://github.com/meteor/readable-stream.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'
npm ERR!
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-02-19T18_15_27_973Z-debug.log
```

Then ran in cmd as Admin and it worked

```
c:\meteor\simple-todos>meteor npm i --save font-awesome
+ font-awesome@4.7.0
updated 1 package in 5.707s
```